# Custom UITableViewCell Button selected - reload data

Tags: ios, uitableview

Alright let's say I have two ViewController, FirstViewController that contains a table and the CustomCell. I set up the action of the button in the CustomCell and it does what it is supposed to do but I want to call the [tableView reloadData] function in my FirstViewController.
What is the proper way of calling this function after the button is selected? Is there a way to set up something in FirstViewController that gets called when the Button in the other Class is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet, if I understand your question correctly, is to use the Delegate Protocol in the second view, which returns a message to the first view controller.

See my answer here on how to setup a delegate:

[How to declare events and delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331523/how-to-declare-events-and-delegates-in-objective-c/21331771#21331771)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Everything works perfectly fine now