# Objective C - Unrecognized delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, delegates

I am new to Objective C and trying to grasp the concept of a delegate. I have the following code and have made comments where a warning and an error occur with the build.I am using the latest version of Xcode and using a Storyboard.

From MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FinalViewController.h"

@class MainViewController;
@protocol MainViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)sayHello;
@end

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MainViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (void)writeToMe;
. . .
@end
```

From MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "FinalViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController ()
@end

@implementation MainViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)writeToMe
{
    [self.delegate sayHello];
}
. . .
@end
```

From FinalViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController <NSCoding, MainViewController> //The ERROR below appears
    //ERROR:Cannot find protocol declaration for ‘MainViewControllerDelegate’; did you mean ‘UIPageViewControllerDelegate’?
    . . .
@end
```

From FinalViewController.m

```
#import "FinalViewController.h"
@interface FinalViewController ()
@end

@implementation FinalViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MainViewController *mainVC;
    mainVC.delegate = self; //causes WARNING below
    //WARNING:Assigning to ‘id <MainViewControllerDelegate> from incompatible type ‘FinalViewController *const__strong’

    [mainVC writeToMe];
    . . .
}

- (void)sayHello
{
    NSLog(@"sayHello called");
}
@end
```

I have researched problems and responses to a similar problem on this web site, but have not found a solution using Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "FinalViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController ()
@end

@implementation MainViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)writeToMe
{
    [self.delegate sayHello];
}
. . .
```

TO:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
@interface MainViewController ()
@end

@implementation MainViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)writeToMe
{
    [self.delegate sayHello];
}
. . .
```

ALSO:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FinalViewController.h"

@class MainViewController;
@protocol MainViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)sayHello;
@end

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <MainViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (void)writeToMe;
. . .
@end
```

TO

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol MainViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)sayHello;
@end

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MainViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (void)writeToMe;
. . .
@end
```

--------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------

Change

```
@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController <NSCoding, MainViewController>
```

to

```
@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController <NSCoding, MainViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: CW0007007: I changed code as you recommended and still get the same error.

Comment: CW0007007: The Build is successful, however the NSLog statement does not appear in the console.

Comment: See my answer here on how to properly setup a delegate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331523/how-to-declare-events-and-delegates-in-objective-c/21331771#21331771

Answer (score 0):

This might be a typo but:

```
@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController <NSCoding, MainViewController>
```

should be:

```
@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController <NSCoding, MainViewControllerDelegate>
```

Also remove the import of `"FinalViewController.h"` from `MainViewController.h`.

And your other warning can be fixed by changing:

```
@interface FinalViewController ()
```

to:

```
@interface FinalViewController () < MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

and change:

```
mainVC.delegate = self;
```

to:

```
mainVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Comment: maddy: Deletion of the FinalViewController.h imports resulted in a successful build, but the protocol method was not called. Adding < MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> resulted in an Error stating that the protocol could not be located.